# does disabling a track of WebRTC stop consuming the bandwidth?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am creating a project where the user is connected through webRTC to a few other users, however, they won't see each other all the time.
So I am thinking in setting the remote track's enable property to false and set it to true when needed.
Before testing this I would like to know if disabling the track will also stop network traffic.

Internet is very poor in some places and the idea is to spare the user's bandwidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't. You can easily observe that by going to
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/bandwidth/
and then execute the following JS:
localStream.getTracks().forEach(t => t.enabled = !t.enabled)
The bitrate will drop considerably but not be null since this sends black frames.

If you want to actually stop sending the easiest approach is to use the replaceTrack API, replace the audio/video track with a null track and then re-replace it when you want to send again.

Firefox behaves like that out of the box already :-)

Comment: so the streamer must replace its tracks. The receiver has no power to stop receiving, right? I am asking this because the receiver will open a panel where he can see the streamers, so it would be easier if I could just replace the streamer trackers there.

Comment: I'm not yet so deep into webRTC. But is it possible for the receiver to stop a received track? Then, maybe the sender would stop sending it?